# Who is the Assyrian in Ezekiel 31:3

Tags: ezekiel, metaphor

> [Ezekiel 31:3](https://biblehub.com/ezekiel/31-3.htm) Behold, the **Assyrian** was a cedar in Lebanon with
>   fair branches, and with a shadowing shroud, and of an high stature;
>   and his top was among the thick boughs.

This Assyrian mentioned above seems to have been in the **Garden of Eden**

> [Ezekiel 31:9](https://biblehub.com/ezekiel/31-9.htm) I have made him fair by the multitude of his
>   branches: so that all the trees of **Eden**, that were in the **garden of
>   God**, envied him.

Who is this Assyrian? As we know that only human beings in the Garden of Eden were Adam & Eve.

Answer (score 2):

Ezekiel 31 is a prophecy directed against Egypt, but he delivers his warning by speaking about Assyria. This warning is presented in the language of trees in a forest:

It is as if 'the Assyrian' was the tallest, strongest tree in God's garden in Eden. All the birds preferred Assyria over the other trees, and rivers flowed from Assyria's tree, and the other trees became envious Assyria. Assyria grew proud, but because of Assyria's arrogance, God handed Assyria over to the other nations, who cut it down. God then threw Assyria's tree into the underworld, where other trees from Eden, long-dead, rejoiced at its destruction.

The prophecy concludes with Ezekiel spelling his warning out directly, instructing Egypt to learn from Assyria's example.

> Which among the trees of Eden was like you [Egypt] in glory and in greatness?

That is, Egypt thinks itself glorious and great now, but Assyria was once glorious and great as well. Where did that get Assyria?

> Now you [Egypt] shall be brought down with the trees of Eden to the world below; you shall lie among the uncircumcised, with those who are killed by the sword. This is Pharaoh and all his horde, says Yahweh God.

Assyria's tree was cut down and thrown into the underworld, where the trees of Eden rejoiced at its fall. Egypt's fate is to be the same.

'The Assyrian' is not a person. Ezekiel is simply referring to the kingdom of Assyria, which had already been conquered.

Comment: Modern day Germany.

Answer (score 0):

Satan is labeled "the Assyrian that is in My land" in Isaiah 14, where he is also addressed as the king of Babylon.

**Isaiah 14:3-4,12,24-27**

> It shall come to pass in the day the LORD gives you rest from your sorrow, and from your fear and the hard bondage in which you were made to serve, that you will take up this proverb against **the king of Babylon**, and say:
>
> “How the oppressor has ceased,
>   The golden city ceased! ...
>   **How  you are fallen from heaven,**
>   **O Lucifer, son of the morning!**
>   How you are cut down to the ground,
>   You who weakened the nations! ...
>
> The LORD of hosts has sworn, saying,
>   “Surely, as I have thought, so it shall come to pass,
>   And as I have purposed, so it shall stand:
>   That I will break **the Assyrian** in My land,
>   And on My mountains tread him underfoot.
>   Then his yoke shall be removed from them,
>   And his burden removed from their shoulders.
>   This is the purpose that is purposed **against the whole earth**,
>   And this is the hand that is stretched out over all the nations.
>   For the LORD of hosts has purposed,
>   And who will annul it?
>   His hand is stretched out,
>   And who will turn it back?”

You will notice that the Lord here refers to this king of Babylon as "the Assyrian," and this entire passage is speaking of Lucifer, the one who fell from heaven, who has sought to establish his dominion over the whole earth.

The Lord also addresses Satan under the name "the king of Tyre" in Ezekiel 28:

**Ezekiel 28:12-15**

> “Son of man, take up a lamentation for **the king of Tyre**, and say to him, ‘Thus says the Lord GOD:
>
> “You were the seal of perfection,
>   Full of wisdom and **perfect in beauty**.
>   **You were in Eden**, the garden of God;
>   **Every precious stone was your covering**:
>   ...
>   **You were the anointed cherub who covers**;
>   I established you;
>   You were on the holy mountain of God;
>   You walked back and forth in the midst of fiery stones.
>   You were perfect in your ways from the day you were created,
>   Till iniquity was found in you.

Thus, it makes perfect sense that the Lord is employing these things to teach us concerning Satan, who was indeed in the Garden of Eden; who is described as being a most beautiful creature. His kingdom is represented by the king of Tyre, the king of Babylon, the king of Egypt, and all the world empires throughout the ages. His is the kingdom that will ultimately be brought down at the second coming; "the sinful kingdom," as it is called.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE, and thank you for your post!  Feel free to explore the site, take a [tour], or chat with others in [chat]. Looking forward to seeing you around! Consider clarifying your answer by [edit]ing in exact citations or quotes, but thanks for your work!

Comment: I downvoted. "Lucifer" is the Latin word that was used in the Latin Vulgate translation of this passage. In the original Hebrew this passage does not refer to a specific entity by a proper name.

Answer (score 0):

The tree of the assyrian, in Ezekiel 31, is the forbidden tree of life? That Eve ate from. I also think that the genetic exchange that happens as a consequence has somthing to do with coppulation. There are many that claim that Eve slept with Satan but it seems a little far fetched and contrived to me. Whene you look at the fact that Nimrod "BECAME" great and the inferance that his genetics where changed, is this a clue that Eve went through a similar change; in that child birth "BECAME" laborious and painfull. I suppose that giving birth to a nephilem would be painfull as well? Was there a genetic corruption that gave natural rise to both DEATH and PAINFULL CHILD BIRTH? Have we been corrupted from the beginning of that age?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Far reaching I know but here goes...

“This calls for a mind with wisdom: the seven heads are seven mountains on which the woman is seated; they are also seven kings, five of whom have fallen, one is, the other has not yet come, and when he does come he must remain only a little while. As for the beast that was and is not, it is an eighth but it belongs to the seven, and it goes to destruction.”
‭‭Revelation‬ ‭17:9-11‬ ‭ESV‬‬

The Assyrian being the antichrist and His spirit was in seven kings, which at the time of revelation five kings had already lived under the antichrist spirit, one king was ruling that had the spirit guiding him and a seventh will come that will only be for a little while and there is an eighth who is resurrected (I won’t speculate on who these kings are, but it is always associated with a world ruler that tries to get rid of the nation G d made for Himself through Abraham, Isaac and Jacob).

“The beast that you saw was, and is not, and is about to rise from the bottomless pit and go to destruction. And the dwellers on earth whose names have not been written in the book of life from the foundation of the world will marvel to see the beast, because it was and is not and is to come.”
‭‭Revelation‬ ‭17:8‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Notice that the beast was, is not and is to come. This is understood to be Nimrod who was technically an Assyrian based on geography, he was after the Babel encounter due to the diversification of languages known by many names including Gilgamesh, Osiris, the Bible calls him Appolion or Apollo but is one and the same and this passage is saying that though He is not now, he will be resurrected from the dead and DWELLERS will marvel at the beast what was, is not and will be. His spirit has been in previous seven kings.

He is coming on the scene for destruction.

Essentially Nimrod is believed to have become a Nephilim not through genetics but through sorcery and incantation. He essentially invited a satanic entity or satan himself to indwell him and take dominion over the earth using his body as an instrument. satan we know was in the garden of Eden and Nimrod we understand from Jewish writings suffered a head wound. He seems to fit.

It’s messy but this is AN explanation. Also it’s believed that Nimrod’s body was discovered and preserved in perfect condition in Iraq a week before the Iraqi invasion in the 2003 and conspiracy has it that “they” are working through ancient occult ritual practices to resurrect or through genetics found in the mummified body to recreate him. The ancestry DNA craze is merely an attempt to find those with markers on the X chromosome (think x-men) that have Nephilim genetics or seed from the sons of G d that came down to earth in Genesis 6

These are not considered the same as

“And the dwellers on earth whose names have not been written in the book of life from the foundation of the world”

But these dwellers are the offsprings of the initial sons of G d and women who copulated together because they did not have a NEPHESH and cannot return to G d they are trapped on the earth as disembodied spirits and would become the daimons or the demons who do the bidding of their fathers the fallen sons of G d in Genesis 6 spoken about by Peter and Jude who abandoned their abode.

Technically just because the human gene pool is contaminated with angelic genes/seed so long as the father and mother are human the offspring has a nephesh and can be saved by the Blood of Jesus. These daimons cannot because their names were never written in the book of life from before creation. Out of the book of life you can either remain or be expunged but no verse shows that a name can be added or written in.

Also concerning the Assyrian and cedars

“"Yet it was I who destroyed the Amorite before them, whose height was like the height of the cedars and who was as strong as the oaks; I destroyed his fruit above and his roots beneath.”
‭‭Amos‬ ‭2:9‬ ‭ESV‬‬

The Amorites were as tall as cedars and while many dispute that there were giants 20-60feet tall because there is no skeletal evidence, bones unless fossilized done last more than 1,000 years in the ground. Anyhow

This Amorites are considered to have been giants because they inherited genetics from before the flood that crossed over the WORLD WIDE flood into the new world and therefore had Nephilim genetics. By the time of David these giants started getting smaller because the genetics was being diluted.

Comment: What is the "new world" that you are referring to into which the amorites crossed over?

Comment: The genes or the seed from the fallen elohim that gave rise to the cross between humans and elohim was before the flood. The flood wiped out everything on land and in air except those in the ark and waters. The new world is the world after the flood. The genes get transferred and there are several hypotheses how, I personally don’t ascribe to other elohim copulating with human women, I’m more in favor of the wives of the sons of Noah carrying the genes which is probably why Noah cursed Canaan rather than Ham who tries to sleep with his mother seeing that his own offspring has Nephilim traits.

Comment: This is why I think the Assyrian is the antiChrist of Revelations “For thus says the Lord GOD: “My people went down at first Into Egypt to dwell there; Then the Assyrian oppressed them without cause.”
‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭52:4‬ ‭NKJV‬‬
As you can see this new Pharoah that didn’t know Joseph was not of the same dynasty but Assyrian

Comment: Assyria is modern day Germany.  I hope I don't get in too much trouble for saying that.

Answer (score -1):

The Bible says that there was an Assyrian tree bigger than all the trees in the garden right. It was amazing. But the bible never specifically says that it was in the garden. It was in Eden but it is not in the garden. So this means that it was so huge that these trees could see it. Now, when this tree fell, the other trees fainted. The garden was in a different location but in Eden. The stump of the Assyrian actually is in Lebanon. It is the mountain in Lebonon. Now look. Before the flood there were gigantic trees of mega proportions. But when they fell they left stumps. Then came the flood. These stumps were then petrified. and turned to stone. Ezekiel 31 never states that this tree was in the garden. And the tree was used as a representation after as it grew and fell. It did happen but god told Ezekiel... Remind pharaoh about that tree. Remember that tree, and how it placed its self above all. Remember this tree that other great trees envied? Remember? It wasn't a threat, it was a promise. He said stop. Who do you think u are. Stop or like this tree your nation will become. Amen?

Comment: Hello Yonny, welcome to BHSE, glad to have you here! If you have time, please make sure to take our tour (https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works and how were are different than other sites. Thanks!